# wildfly 15 , undertow 2.0.15 null pointer exception

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

i am trying to accede to api servlet localhost:8080/app/api but im getting a null pointer.
my servlet mapping is as follow :

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

the exception :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getHttpServletMapping(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:247)
        at javax.servlet.api@1.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHttpServletMapping(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:164)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper$Servlet4Delegate.skipServletPathDetermination(UrlPathHelper.java:780)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.skipServletPathDetermination(UrlPathHelper.java:272)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.getLookupPathForRequest(UrlPathHelper.java:251)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.resolvePath(UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.java:260)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.getCorsConfiguration(UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.java:244)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:86)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at deployment.app.war//org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
```

ps i have already tried to change the url pattern of the servlet to be /api
it works but i want to use a proper solution with /api/*

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem as you. The issue seems to be due to a bug in WildFly 15 ([refer to this link](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/280621)).

As a workaround, you can change the servlet-mapping like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```